How do I add a new input box?
I created an input field where you can add a new input box by pressing the green button. However, when the user types in the input box(service, quantity or price), and press the green button the input from the first inbox gets copied. When the user clicks on the green button, I want a blank input boxes to appear.
I know the issue is somewhere in my JS but I can’t figure it out. Can anyone help?


function create_tr(table_id) {
  let table_body = document.getElementById(table_id),
    first_tr = table_body.firstElementChild
  tr_clone = first_tr.cloneNode(true);
  table_body.append(tr_clone);

  clean_first_tr(table_body.firstElementChild);

}

function clean_first_tr(firstTr) {
  let children = firstTr.children;

  children = Array.isArray(children) ? children : Object.values(childern);
  childern.forEach(x => {

    if (x !== firstTr.lastElementChild) {
      console.log(x.firstElementChild.value = '');
    }
  });
}

function remove_tr(This) {
  if (This.closest('tbody').childElementCount == 1) {
    alert("yo cant")
  } else {
    This.closest('tr').remove();
  }
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(107, 103, 103);
}

button {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 900px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 20px #0001, 0 1px 6px #0001;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

._table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

._table :is( th, td) {
  border: 1px solid #0002;
  padding: 8px 10px;
}


/* From feild design start*/

.form_control {
  border: 1px solid #0002;
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: none;
  font-family: 1rem;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #333;
  /*font-family: ;*/
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.form_control ::placeholder {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.form_contro:is(:focus):hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 6px #0002;
}

.add {
  background-color: #24b96f !important;
}

.warning {
  background-color: #ebba33 !important;
}

.primary {
  background-color: #259df2 !important;
}

.secondary {
  background-color: #00bcd4 !important;
}

.remove {
  background-color: #ff5722 !important;
}

.action_conatiner {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.action_conatiner>* {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.action_conatiner>*+* {
  background-color: red !important;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff5;
}

.action_conatiner>*:hover {
  filter: hue-rotate(-20deg) brightness(0.97);
  transform: scale(1.05);
  border-color: transparent;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px #0004;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.action_conatiner>*:active {
  transition: unset;
  transform: scale(.99);
}


/* From feild design end*/
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Add Remove</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <table class="_table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Service</th>
          <th>QTY</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th width="50px">
            <div class="action_conatiner">
              <button class="add" onclick="create_tr('table_body')"></button>
            </div>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="table_body">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="text" class=" form_control" placeholder="website">
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="number" class=" form_control" min="0" placeholder="0">
          </td>
          <td>
            <input data-type="currency" class=" form_control" placeholder="$0.00">
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="action_conatiner">
              <button class="remove" onclick="remove_tr(this)">
                
                  </button>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>

  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>




Typo: childern should be children. Is that a copying error or in the real code?

When you clone the <tr>, I believe it clones the values too, so you'd need to clear the values of the inputs in the cloned node. It seems very similar to your clean_first_tr() function; in fact, I think you could just pass the cloned node to that function.

You can use Array.from(firstTr.children).

But is it a typo in the real code, or only here? You should have gotten an error message in the console.

fixing the typo should fix the issue.

@bamar it was a typo in the real code

One more question. Why doesn't my first input box get pused further down when you add new boxes? It stays in that second row?

You're appending the new row at the end of the table, not the beginning, so none of the old rows should be pushed down.

Other than fixing the children typo, I can see that you want to add the new row to the top and push the others down. For that, you need to use prepend instead of append to add the tr_clone to the top.
Here is the full code with comments explaining the changes:


function create_tr(table_id) {
    let table_body = document.getElementById(table_id),
        first_tr = table_body.firstElementChild
    let tr_clone = first_tr.cloneNode(true);  // use let keyword
    table_body.prepend(tr_clone);  // use prepend to add the tr_clone to the top

    clean_first_tr(table_body.firstElementChild);
}

function clean_first_tr(firstTr) {
    let children = firstTr.children;
    
    // fixed childern to children
    children = Array.isArray(children) ? children : Object.values(children);
    children.forEach(x => {

        if (x !== firstTr.lastElementChild) {
            console.log(x.firstElementChild.value = '');
        }
    });
}

function remove_tr(This) {
    if (This.closest('tbody').childElementCount === 1) {
        alert("yo cant")
    } else {
        This.closest('tr').remove();
    }
}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: rgb(107, 103, 103);
}

button {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}

.container {
    max-width: 900px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 20px #0001, 0 1px 6px #0001;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

._table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

._table :is( th, td) {
    border: 1px solid #0002;
    padding: 8px 10px;
}


/* From feild design start*/

.form_control {
    border: 1px solid #0002;
    background-color: transparent;
    outline: none;
    font-family: 1rem;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    width: 100%;
    color: #333;
    /*font-family: ;*/
    transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.form_control ::placeholder {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.form_contro:is(:focus):hover {
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 6px #0002;
}

.add {
    background-color: #24b96f !important;
}

.warning {
    background-color: #ebba33 !important;
}

.primary {
    background-color: #259df2 !important;
}

.secondary {
    background-color: #00bcd4 !important;
}

.remove {
    background-color: #ff5722 !important;
}

.action_conatiner {
    display: inline-flex;
}

.action_conatiner>* {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px 14px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.action_conatiner>*+* {
    background-color: red !important;
    border-left: 1px solid #fff5;
}

.action_conatiner>*:hover {
    filter: hue-rotate(-20deg) brightness(0.97);
    transform: scale(1.05);
    border-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 10px #0004;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

.action_conatiner>*:active {
    transition: unset;
    transform: scale(.99);
}


/* From feild design end*/
<div class="container">
    <table class="_table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Service</th>
            <th>QTY</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th width="50px">
                <div class="action_conatiner">
                    <button class="add" onclick="create_tr('table_body')"></button>
                </div>
            </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="table_body">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class=" form_control" placeholder="website">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" class=" form_control" min="0" placeholder="0">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input data-type="currency" class=" form_control" placeholder="$0.00">
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="action_conatiner">
                    <button class="remove" onclick="remove_tr(this)">

                    </button>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>



